# Difference between R² and Chi-Square

Tags: regression, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, r-squared

The question is in the title: In both cases I use $R^2$ and chi-square to test if a fit/model is good enough. Up to now I only know that $R^2$ is used for models (?) and chi-square for fits/functions (?). Is this true? And how exactly do they differ?

Comment: The answer to this would almost amount to a complete introductory statistics course. Can you narrow it down a bit to a specific scientific analysis where you are in doubt what to do?

Comment: I'm just learning these two terms because I always stumble over them. And it confuses me. Also what's the difference between max likelihood and chi-square..    for me they are all doing the same and it's a bit hard to separate them (for me).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found this after a quick Google search:

> $R^2$ is used to quantify the amount of variability in the data that
> is explained by your model. It's useful for comparing the fits of
> different models.
>
> The chi-square goodness of fit test is used to test if your data
> follows a particular distribution. It's more useful for testing model
> assumptions rather than comparing models.

Sounds like the chi-square is more useful if you have a function you are trying to test (or a model you are trying to fit to your data) as opposed to the $R^2$, which tells you how much variability there is in your data, and therefore how much the best model fits.

Comment: Thanks! So that's my assumption :) But thanks anyway! Of interested is now how/why they are applied to different cases respectively in which way they work differently.

Answer (score 1):

The chi-square provides a **per-feature** measurement of **dependency with the target**. This is useful at the **feature-selection stage**, for a classification model. We'd like to weed out the low-dependent features.
([scikit-learn guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#univariate-feature-selection) for additional such measurements for classification and regression models).

$R^2$ provides a **model-level** measurement of the **target's variance explained**. This is useful at the **model-evaluation stage**. ([scikit-learn guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score) for $R^2$)